# Famo.us and Font-Awesome

Tags: gruntjs, font-awesome, famo.us

anyone experienced issues while distributing a project with grunt including font awesome?

My problem is that on the final distribution project inside "dist" folder i miss font-awesome...

Font-Awesome folder in my project is located in:

> app/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css

What i've done so far:
i tried to edit copy.js (in grunt folder) like this:

```
src: [
        '**/**.{ico,png,gif,txt,jpg,svg,wof,ttf}',
        '.htaccess',
        //'images/{,*/}*.webp',
        //'content/{*.*,*/}*.*',
        'content/{,*/}/{,*/}/*.*',
        // '{,*/}*.html',
        'styles/fonts/{*.*,*/}*.*',
        'lib/famous/**/**.css',
        'lib/font-awesome/{,*/}/**.css'
      ]
```

..to distribute font-awesome too and now it is in the dist folder but when i open index.html it just can't seem to find the correct path and i see no icon.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try a link tag directly in your index.html file?

Answer (score 0):

To simplify everything and speed up loading, you could just link to a CDN hosted version of Font Awesome. BootstrapCDN will serve it for you: http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/#fontawesome_tab

Answer (score 0):

Given that you've got this in index.html:

```
    <!-- build:css(app/) css/app.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="content/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/app.css" />
    <!-- bower:css -->
```

Grunt will place the font awesome css in dist/css.  The problem is that font-awesome is looking for fonts relative to this file (../fonts), and the fonts did not move along with the css during the build process.  So, alter your grunt/copy.js file to do this for you:

```
// Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
module.exports = {
  dist: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      dot: true,
      cwd: '<%= config.app %>',
      dest: '<%= config.dist %>',
      src: [
        '**/**.{ico,png,txt,jpg,svg,wof,ttf}',
        '.htaccess',
        'images/{,*/}*.webp',
        // '{,*/}*.html',
        'styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*',
        'lib/famous/**/**.css'
      ]
    },
    // add this, making sure the path is correct to your fonts
    {
        expand: true,
        dot: true,
        cwd: '<%= config.app %>/content/vendor/font-awesome/fonts/',
        src: ['*.*'],
        dest: '<%= config.dist %>/fonts'

    }]
  }
};
```

run grunt again, and the dist folder should now contain a fonts folder.